# updating a element inside a xml using dom

Tags: java, xml, dom

I've created a xml in the following manner :

```
public static Document baseTemplate(String topLevel,String[] pkey) throws ParserConfigurationException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.newDocument();
    Element top = doc.createElement(topLevel);
    for(int i= 0;i<pkey.length;i++){
        Element child = doc.createElement(pkey[i]);
        top.appendChild(child);        
    }
    doc.appendChild(top);
    return doc;
}
```

This creates a dummy xml such as  based on the inputs passed for the topLevel and individual elements within it.

Now I want to be able to update the individual elements with values later on.Based on the inputs passed,the xml structure will be generic.Similarly update logic also got to be generic.How do I achieve it?

Comment: How do you achieve what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, "*Use XPATH to edit XML or create XML"*, For every **new input passed** you need have the **XPATH** upto that tag which node you want to update, Try something like this:

```
Document doc = /*you have this in your code */
XModifier modifier = new XModifier(doc);
modifier.addModify("//PersonList/Person[2]/Name", "newName");
modifier.modify();
```

You can find more on XModifier here: https://github.com/shenghai/xmodifier
Hope that will help you.